# Prove that $\log_27×\log_29<9$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms, exponential-function, jensen-inequality

**Prove that 
$\log_27×\log_29<9$.**

I've tried couple of things like
multiplying both sides by $\log_28$
Or… moving $\log_29$ to the right which would make everything look like this:
$\log_27<\log_9512$

I tried some more things which didn't give anything as well
I know this isn't something i should ask (because there isn't anything hard) but my brain doesn't work right now and i don't want to waste that much time on this
So i would be thankful if anyone gave somewhat hint or the solution.

Comment: You could start by comparing  $\sqrt{\log_27×\log_29}$ and $\frac{\log_27+\log_29}{2}$

Comment: Yeah that worked thanks

Comment: In case you were replying to my comment, I deleted it because it was completely wrong!

Comment: Yes i know, i was replying the first one

Answer (score 2):

As Henry mentioned in the comments:

$$(\log_27)(\log_29) < \left(\frac{\log_27+\log_29}{2} \right)^2 = \left(\frac{\log_2 63}{2} \right)^2 < \left(\frac{\log_2 64}{2} \right)^2 = 3^2=9$$

Alternatively, as $(x-3)(y-3) = xy - 3(x+y) + 9$, we rearrange for $xy$ to get:

$$(\log_27)(\log_29) = (\log_27 - 3)(\log_29 - 3) + 3(\log_27 + \log_29) - 9$$

$$< 0 + 3 \log_2 63 - 9  < 3 \log_2 64 - 9 = 18-9=9.$$

as $\log_27 - 3 < 0, \log_29 - 3 > 0$ between the first and second line.

Comment: I see that, your answer is the best here. So, let me +1.

Answer (score 1):

We have,

$$\begin{align}&\log_27\times\log_29<9\\
\iff&\frac{\log_27}{3}\times \frac{\log_29}{3}<1\\
\iff&\log_87×\log_89<1\\
\iff&\log_98>\log_87.\end{align}$$

It is a well-known fact that, $f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{\ln (x+1)}$ is a strictly increasing function. (see: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868386/prove-without-differentiation-that-log-n1n-is-increasing?noredirect=1))

[image]

Thus, you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I just loved the problem:

- [**Using AM-GM inequality**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)

$$\begin{align*}
\log_2(7)×\log_2(9) 
& ≤ \left(\frac{\log_2(7) + \log_2(9)}{2}\right)^2\\
& ≤ \left({\frac{\log_2(63)}{2}}\right)^2\\
& < \left({\frac{\log_2(64)}{2}}\right)^2\\
& < \left({\frac{\log_2({2^6})}{2}}\right)^2\\
& < \left({\frac{3×{2\log_2(2)}}{2}}\right)^2\\
& < 9\left(\frac{\log_2(2)}{1}\right)\\
& < 9
\end{align*}$$

- **Using Calculus**

$$3 = \log_2(8) = 3×\log_2(2)$$

$$(\log_2{8} = 3) > \log_2(7)  =  3-\delta_1$$
$$(\log_2{8} = 3) < \log_2(9) = 3+\delta_2$$
Now here, $\delta_2<\delta_1$

- How
  $$\frac{d}{dx}\log(x) = \frac{1}{x}$$
  $\implies $ for higher values of $x$ the increment in $\log(x)$ starts decreasing.

$$\begin{align*}
\log_2(7)×\log_2(9)
& = (3-\delta_1)(3+\delta_2)\\
& = 3.3 + 3(\delta_2-\delta_1) -\delta_1\delta_2\\
& = 9+n_1-n_2\\
&= 9-N\\
&<9
\end{align*}$$

Where, $n_1 = 3(\delta_2-\delta_1)$, $n_2 = \delta_2\delta_1$
, and $N>0$

Where  $n_1<0$ and $n_2>0$

---

Answer (score -1):

Since $(\ln\ln{x})''=-\frac{1+\ln{x}}{x^2\ln^2x}<0$ for $x>1$ and $e^x$ increases, by Jensen we obtain:
$$\log_27\log_29=\frac{e^{\ln\ln7+\ln\ln9}}{\ln^22}\leq\frac{e^{2\ln\ln\frac{7+9}{2}}}{\ln^22}=9.$$